# How to change keyboard layout to qwertz in Cosmos OS?

Tags: c#, cosmos

I'm trying to make a little operating system in C#. I'm using the Cosmos SDK. I have come to the keyboard settings and want to change the keyboard layout.

The default is QWERTY. How could the layout be changed to QWERTZ.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
Cosmos.System.KeyboardManager.SetKeyLayout()
```

I dont know how this works, but should hopefully clear up something.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30063000)